# Is $|xy|^{2/3} = (xy)^{2/3}$?

Tags: calculus

> Can we say $$|xy|^{2/3} = (xy)^{2/3}$$

Can we take the absolute value out consider $ x, y $ are real numbers?

Comment: Depends on how $b^{\frac 23} $ was defined. If it is $[b^2]^{\frac 13} $, yes you can. If it is $e\frac 23\log b $ you can't.

Comment: If we define,  $x^{2/3}=(x^2)^{1/3}$  Then clearly the answer is yes because the function $f(x)=(x^2)^{1/3}$ is even and thus it's value does not depend on sign of the argument.  Similarly if we define it as,  $(x^{1/3})^2$  Again we have an even function, and again sign does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

How would you explain your way out of this?

$(-1)^{\frac 26} = (-1)^{\frac 13} = -1$

$(-1)^{\frac 26} = ((-1)^2)^{\frac 16}=1^{\frac 16}=1$

### addendum

You could just ask if $|x|^{\frac 23} = x^{\frac 23}$

This is obviously true when $x \ge 0$

If it works for one negative number, it should work for all of them. So we compute

$|-1|^{\frac 23} = 1$

$(-1)^{\frac 23} = \left((-1)^2 \right)^{\frac 13} =1^{\frac 13} = 1$

$(-1)^{\frac 23} = \left((-1)^{\frac 13} \right)^1 = (-1)^2 = 1$

So, yes, it seems to be true.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou : Why is $(-1)^{\frac 13}$ a complex number?  Also, complex numbers invlove multi-valued functions and a lot of other complexities. An equal sign between multivalued complex functions is a very difficult task to accomplish.

Comment: Wow is it really that for $x<0$ we have $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ is ill defined. I was told that it is perfectly defined but that $(x^{a})^{b}$ is not $x^{ab} for $x<0$, this example exploits that.  I'm confused, why is like this?

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla, see my comment below Michael's answer. It's because rational numbers are equivalence classes to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I think if we write $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ then we need $x>0$ by definition.

Thus, in my opinion, the answer is "no":
$$|xy|^{\frac{2}{3}}\neq(xy)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

For example, $$(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}=-2$$ is wrong by definition.

By the way, $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$.

Let $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Thus, the domain of $f$ is $(0,+\infty)$.

This definition come from the following things.

Let $f(x)=x^{r}$, where $r\in\mathbb Q$.

$(-2)^2=4$, but $(-2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is undefined.

$0^2=0$, but $0^{-1}$ is undefined and $0^0$ is undefined.

Id est, if we wish to work with the function $f$ then we must assume $x>0$.

By the way, the domain of $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Why would you need x > 0?

Comment: Because a negative number to a fractional power isn't defined.

Comment: But $(-8)^{1/3}=-2$, following the convention of many authors, at least.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs I fixed my post. See now, please.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs, $-2 = (-8)^{1/3} = (-8)^{2/6} = 64^{1/6} = 2$ is why $x^{p/q}$ is ill-defined for negative $x$.

Comment: @Ennar What do you think about my explaining?

Comment: @continuity I fixed my post. See now, please.

Comment: Michael, the only think I'd add to your answer is _why_ we need $x>0$, the reason being that $p/q$ and $2p/2q$ represent the same rational by definition, yet $x^{p/q}$ and $x^{2p/2q}$ might have different signs. Otherwise, your explanation is fine. I like that you emphasize the difference with $\sqrt[q]{x^p}$.

Comment: @Ennar Yes, $(-1)^2=1$ and $(-1)^{\frac{4}{2}}$ is undefined! All these we need for possibility to work with the function $f(x)=x^r$.